# Getting response of a DLL in C

Tags: c++, c

I've follow the next tutorial:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tkc9y5(v=vs.80).aspx

It is working fine for me. But I need to printf the response of the callbackfunctions:

```
printf(uReturnVal);
```

I get the error: `cannot convert argument 1 from 'UINT' to 'const char *const '`

I've tried another options:

```
printf(Convert.ToString(uReturnVal)); //ERROR :'Convert': undeclared identifier [
```

And:

```
printf(uReturnVal->ToString()); //ERROR: '->ToString' must point to class/struct/union/generic
```

And:

```
printf(uReturnVal.ToString());//error: /ERROR: '->ToString' must point to class/struct/union/generic
```

This is the code of the tutorial:

```
typedef UINT (CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNC1)(DWORD,UINT);

HINSTANCE hDLL;               // Handle to DLL
LPFNDLLFUNC1 lpfnDllFunc1;    // Function pointer
DWORD dwParam1;
UINT  uParam2, uReturnVal;

hDLL = LoadLibrary("MyDLL");
if (hDLL != NULL)
{
   lpfnDllFunc1 = (LPFNDLLFUNC1)GetProcAddress(hDLL,
                                           "DLLFunc1");
   if (!lpfnDllFunc1)
   {
      // handle the error
      FreeLibrary(hDLL);
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      // call the function
      uReturnVal = lpfnDllFunc1(dwParam1, uParam2);
   }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First argument to `printf` functions is always format specifier. In your case `printf("%u\n",uReturnVal)` should work. See [Format Specification Syntax: printf and wprintf Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx).

**To Expand:**
The code above is pure C.

You can also do it in C++ style, even more elegant:

```
#include <iostream>
...
  uReturnVal = lpfnDllFunc1(dwParam1, uParam2);
  std::cout << "Result is: " << uReturnVal << std::endl;
```

Comment: GREAT! It works perfect! Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: Also in C and C++ basic types are not objects, so you can't call methods on them (`std::string` is a class, not basic type). Actually there is no elegant, universal and portable way to convert number to string in C, the closest being `sprintf(outputString, "%d", number)`. In modern C++ (C++11) there is `to_string` function.